# How do I decouple an embedded schema within a WSDL?

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I am very new to Web services and I would like to know how one would go about saving types define in a wsdl:type section into it's own schema with the idea that one could reuse the schema within multiple WSDL. I have been trying to use the import statement as per below but this has not been very successful.

```
     <wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://ttdev.com/ss">
   <xsd:import namespace="http://ttdev.com/ss"schemaLocation="http://ttdev.com/ss/SimpleService.xsd"/>
  </xsd:schema>
 </wsdl:types>

<wsdl:definitions 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://ttdev.com/ss" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="SimpleService" targetNamespace="http://ttdev.com/ss" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
 <wsdl:types>
 <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://ttdev.com/ss">
  <xsd:element name="concatRequest">
   <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="param1" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="param2" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="concatResponse">
   <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="100">
     <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
     <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
 </wsdl:types>
 <wsdl:message name="concatRequest">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:concatRequest"/>
 </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:message name="concatResponse">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:concatResponse"/>
 </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:portType name="SimpleService">
  <wsdl:operation name="concat">
   <wsdl:input message="tns:concatRequest"/>
   <wsdl:output message="tns:concatResponse"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
 </wsdl:portType>
 <wsdl:binding name="SimpleServiceSOAP" type="tns:SimpleService">
  <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <wsdl:operation name="concat">
   <soap:operation soapAction="http://ttdev.com/ss/NewOperation"/>
   <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
   </wsdl:input>
   <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
   </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
 </wsdl:binding>
 <wsdl:service name="SimpleService">
  <wsdl:port name="p1" binding="tns:SimpleServiceSOAP">
   <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ss/p1"/>
  </wsdl:port>
 </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

To summarize:

1. I have isolated the schema into its own file SinpleService.xsd (as per code sample below)
2. I have added an import statement to the WSDL as per above.
3. However it looks like types cannot be resolved when I reference them via the import.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="http://ttdev.com/ss" targetNamespace="http://ttdev.com/ss">
 <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
 <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
 <xsd:element name="concatRequest">
  <xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="param1" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="param2" type="xsd:string"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
 <xsd:element name="concatResponse">
  <xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="100">
    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: `import` is the correct approach, stick with it. Tell us why it's not working.

Comment: The WSDL is failing the validation, this is the error i get back:
 C:\Users\User\workspace\Axis2SimpleService\src\main\resources\SimpleService.wsdl is not valid. Character 's' is grammatically unexpected Reason: one of the following is expected (see below) '/>' '>' S Details XML production: Production 'element' not satisfied

Comment: xsd:import : missing space after namespace attribute?

Comment: I which it was that simple maybe if I add the full error trace it will shed light on the problem:

File C:\Users\User\workspace\Axis2SimpleService\src\main\resources\SimpleService.wsdl is not valid.
 attribute 'element' in message part 'parameters' (message 'concatRequest') refers to element 'tns:concatRequest' which is not defined within the WSDL file!
  Error location: wsdl:definitions / wsdl:message / wsdl:part / @element

Comment: namespace issue with 'tns:', try to remove that optional 'tns:' from your wsdl:definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

SimpleServiceSchema.xsd:

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://ttdev.com/ss/include" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:complexType name="concatRequestType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="param1" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="param2" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="concatResponseType">
        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="100">
            <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>


<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://ttdev.com/ss" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:inc="http://ttdev.com/ss/include" name="SimpleService" targetNamespace="http://ttdev.com/ss">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://ttdev.com/ss">
            <xsd:import namespace="http://ttdev.com/ss/include" schemaLocation="SimpleServiceSchema.xsd"/>
            <xsd:element name="concatRequest" type="inc:concatRequestType"/>
            <xsd:element name="concatResponse" type="inc:concatResponseType"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="concatRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:concatRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="concatResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:concatResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="SimpleService">
        <wsdl:operation name="concat">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:concatRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:concatResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="SimpleServiceSOAP" type="tns:SimpleService">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="concat">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://ttdev.com/ss/NewOperation"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="SimpleService">
        <wsdl:port name="p1" binding="tns:SimpleServiceSOAP">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ss/p1"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

(thank you, XMLSpy)

Comment: Maybe this is more an XML question than web service but why do you need to define the complexe type inside the schema and then define the actual element within the wsdl. Would it be posible to define the element inside the schema as well ?

Comment: @user: no, that's a WSDL question. The answer is that's the way they wrote it. And, no, in this case, you need the element to be in a namespace specific to the service. If used in a different service, it will be in a different namespace, yet will be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

You need a space after the quotation mark:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://ttdev.com/ss"schemaLocation="http://ttdev.com/ss/SimpleService.xsd"/>
```

should be

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://ttdev.com/ss" schemaLocation="http://ttdev.com/ss/SimpleService.xsd"/>
```